# Java CSV writer fails but data is there

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to write the output of a query to a CSV file. I issue three queries to a table with three companies (CompanyA, CompanyB, CompanyC) and output the result of each query to a csv file (A.csv, B.csv, C.csv).

The queries are valid and `System.out.println` (below) produces correct names.

However, when I check the output files only CompanyC is populated. CompanyA and B are blank. I thought it was only processing the last query so I removed C from the query and still A.csv and B.csv are blank. There's no formatting difference between these names and no nulls or anything that could throw off the output. I just can't figure out why ONE of them always works?
Just to reiterate: the query is valid and the console output is correct and what I'm trying to write to those files:

```java
while (rsGroups.next()) {

    String groupcode = rsGroups.getString("GroupCode");
    String groupname = rsGroups.getString("groupname");
    String sqlGetComms = "Select companyname from companies where groupcode ='" + groupcode + "'";
    System.out.println(sqlGetComms);
    ResultSet rs2 = st.executeQuery(sqlGetComms);
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("C:\\temp\\" + groupname + "comms.csv");
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            
    while (rs2.next()) { 
        out.write(rs2.getString("CompanyName") );
        System.out.println(rs2.getString("companyname"));
        out.newLine();
    }
    rs2.close();
            
    fstream.close();
   // fstream.flush();
}
System.out.println("done");
```

Comment: What's `out`? Does it have `.flush()`?

Comment: To avoid people guessing what the problem might be, please post a [mcve]

Comment: In addition to `out`, what is `fstream`? Could you post all of the relevant parts? Maybe take a look here: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: First of all your details are imperfect to get the actual solution for you.
But, you can check by adding a delimiter while writing values.

Comment: Not sure what's the difficulty here; put `out.flush();` before `rs2.close()`.

Comment: Use `out.close()` instead of `fstream.close()`, and I highly recommend that you switch to using try-with-resources.

Answer (score 0):

You need `out.close();` instead of `fstream.close();`. This will write, flush, the buffer of the BufferedWriter and close the fstream.

It is a good idea to use the *try-with-resources* syntax instead of closing oneself. Less messy.

Also use the `Files` utility class. For instance File Writer is an old convenience class that uses the default operating system encoding. One might prefer full Unicode with UTF-8.